# Custom navbar depth level always evaluate zero

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new in wordpress, i am creating custom navbar and i pass depth level 3, but it always return 0,
Please help me to find out the error

Below is my code and output

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
    'walker'            => new Walker_Nav_Menu_Page(),
    'container'         => 'ul',
    'menu_class'        => 'top-level',
    'depth'             => 4
));
```

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
{
   var_dump($depth);
}
```

```
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depth should be zero by default, which means all so please remove depth